# Is there a name for prior distributions for which the actual value is in the support / has positive probability?

Tags: statistics, bayesian

I was wondering whether there is a name for prior distribution $P$ over some parameter $\theta$ for which the actual parameter $\theta^*$ is in the support of $P$ (or has positive probability for a discrete prior). I am aware that the whole idea of a prior is to assume that $\theta^*$ is in the support, but generally a prior could also be just "incorrect". So, I was wondering whether there is a name for these "proper"/"correct" priors.

Comment: Not having the actual value in the support of the prior would indicate a failure to have followed [Cromwell's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cromwell%27s_rule): *I beseech you, in the bowels of Christ, think it possible that you may be mistaken.*